# When Build Directory will be generated under e2e

Tags: detox

**Can someone explain when the build directory will be generated under the e2e directory in detox.**

I have done setup, but due to some problem again i am doing it from scratch but got a question when this directory gets created.

Answer (score 1):

detox normally builds your app in the same output directory of xcode or android studio build commands unless you provide other path explicitly in build command in your package.json file.

for ios this is usually projectroot/ios/Build and android projectroot/android/app/build.

if you want other path for your build output use -derivedDataPath  with your xcodebuild command.